# .Net Sql Connection - "The network name cannot be found" from one solution

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

We have a setup on some machines using a database alias as some development environments have Express, while others have full SQL.

I've started getting a strange error in one of my solutions that uses the (local) alias to route to localhost\sqlexpress version. It's only started occurring in the last two weeks, and there is nothing actually wrong with the alias.

The error we are getting in this solution is:

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

We have tested this connection locally, in SqlManagement Studio and in a separate solution, and it works fine in all other scenarios.

When I run the following code in the immediate window of the two instances of visual studio i am running, one works fine, and the other throws the above exception:

```
new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CATALOG;Persist Security Info=True;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;Application Name=APPNAME Local").Open()
```

This is one of the strangest things I've ever seen. I am wondering if there could be some kind of alias override at the project level that I'm unaware of, or anything else that would affect a connection string on a project basis.

All help appreciated.

UPDATE:
Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. But I would like to stress that this connection string is ***valid and works in all other scenarios on the same machine*** outside of the one solution it does not work in. I've tested this with both Named Pipes and TCP/IP and it is the same for both scenarios.

Comment: See this: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: To workaround it, see this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: @MaciejLos (local) is perfectly valid (even if it's not mentioned in connectionstrings.com). It should map to default instance on localhost. What I don't know if it can _automatically_ map to a named instance (like in this case).

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Express. This error is usually caused by not being able to find the server. If the Data Source is correct could it be the provider/connection type is not enable on the server (named pipes as oppposed to TCP/IP for example.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, `(local)` is used when the local machine and server is the same machine. OP wants to connect to server placed on another machine - as per my understanding.

Comment: @MaciejLos _"...solutions that uses the (local) alias to route to **localhost\sqlexpress** version..."_. I'd guess he's talking about local machine (emphasis is mine).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, *We have a setup on some machines...development environments have Express, while others have full SQL*. This statement is quite obviously for me. This does not disqualifies your  opinion. ;)

Comment: It appears to be trying to connect with named pipes as opposed to the normal TCP/IP, is this intentional?

Comment: The connection string is valid outside of the solution it is failing in. I can connect and query on it in a different instance of visual studio, running on the same machine, and it behaves the same for both Named Pipes and TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur by multiple reasons, maybe your firewall it's blocking the connection to the default MSSQL Port, or you have disable the SQL TCP/IP protocol. wich is the default protocol used by System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Class.

To enable this property you must go to "SQL Server Configuration manager", Expand the node with  your instance name and in Client Protocols enable TCP/IP.

I dont Post an image cause i need reputation but it work for me.

**Regards.**

Comment: This is not a problem with the SQL instance as the connection string is valid and works with both TCP/IP and named pipes.

Comment: Yes the connection string is valid, but I said, he should see if those protocols are enabled for this instance in the SQL Manager.

Comment: What would the symptom be if the protocols were not enabled? I assume it wouldn't work at all, and I would be unable to connect with Management Studio or using any SqlConnection objects?

Comment: If you're trying to connect to an instance of SQL Server, with a protocol that is disabled, the client never going to find this instance.

Comment: So the server is definitely running, as the connection string establishes a connection properly and can run any commands I throw at it from a second instance of visual studio.

Comment: He/She,

- Can connect throw Managment Studio - It proves that is runing
- I dont see any problem whith the connection string

But can not run any command until the client be able to find the instance.

Comment: I can run all the commands I need to run against the connection. It executes SQL (Stored Procs, Table and View queries) without a problem.